# Inspecting vi .swp file to preview recovery

Tags: vim, data-recovery

Feel free to close this as a dupe if you can find a question that deals with this case.

This is NOT about HOW to recover a .swp file in vi.

I'm not sure if I want to recover.  I want to preview what I'll be changing if I do, and in a non destructive way.

Unfortunately typing `vi .myfile.swp` shows me what looks like binary gobblety gook.

To make my current state clear, I believe no one is currently editing the file.  I happen to be looking at an overzealous copy of a dir that apparently happened while the file was open.

My current plan is to copy myfile to myfile-temp and then recover myfile.  Then inspect for differences.

Is there a better way?

Comment: I'm also noticing that making a copy of the file and renaming the swp file to match the copy doesn't work.  I can open the copy without vi/m offering to recover.

Comment: The swap file has a struct `block0` (C) that is written to the start of the swap. Among the properties of the struct is the file name `b0_fname`. If you open the swap file in Vim you should be able to locate this field at the top (byte 100+/-) What you need to do is either create a new directory where you copy the swap file and source, or you can edit the swap file IFF you give it a name of same length as original. The latter is more for hack and fun ... Recovering by swap is by default non-destructive for the original file as well as original swap. (Unless `:w`)

Comment: @Sukminder Thanks! What's compelling me to :w is the need to diff.

Comment: Then do as in linked answer. `:sav another_file_name` and then diff *original_file_name* and *another_file_name* ... Perhaps play around with some test files first ...

Comment: Vi does not create such a file. It seems that you are talking about vim.

Comment: @schily, noted.  I've updated my tags

Comment: @Sukminder Thanks again.  I've confirmed that copying the file and it's swap into a dir side steps the swap file knowing the name of the file.  Just wish I had a good glob pattern to copy them both in one line.

Comment: @Sukminder I'll clean my comments as well.  However, aside from that one misstep, your idea of copying both foo and foo.swp is a nice non-destructive solution that I'd like to see as an answer.

Comment: @MagicWindow: If you want to see the diff, see my answer below.  Since I don't know I have a .swp until I try to edit a file, it's a very easy way of just looking at the diff between the two, then deciding the right course of action (keep, revert, delete, etc).

Comment: This is the one single worst thing with Vim.

Answer (score 4):

By far, my favorite vim plugin for handling this is [Recover.vim](https://github.com/chrisbra/Recover.vim).  When you edit a file which has an associated .swp, it gives you the option of showing the diff between the two.  This is invaluable.  For example:

```
$ vi foo.py
...
Please choose:
D[i]ff, (O)pen Read-Only, (E)dit anyway, (R)ecover, (Q)uit, (A)bort, (D)elete:
```

Comment: Rather than be required to install something I my not have permission to install I'd prefer an answer describes the simple work around you mentioned in the comments of the question.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few functions to help with this, see the [relevant page on the Vim wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Swap_file_%22...%22already_exists!_-_so_diff_it).

The article is very long, so I won't copy it all here, but the basic premise is to save to another file and then diff the two.

Comment: The first entry looks promising. It seems to be saving the swp changes to a new file, so it is non destructive.  And even includes doing a diff.  However it does a poor job of explaining steps 1-8.   Could I talk you into improving your answer?

Comment: @MagicWindow I made an attempt at improving the solution from the [vim wiki link](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Swap_file_%22...%22already_exists!_-_so_diff_it). see my improvements here: https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/15584/1894 .